# how does scanf() check if the input is an integer or character?

Tags: c, scanf

I am wondering how does the standard C library function scanf() check if the input is an integer or a character when we call scanf("%d",&var) when a character itself is just a number?
I know that when it encounters a non-integer it puts it back into the input buffer and returns a -1 but how does it know that the input is not an integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct in that each character is really represented as an 8-bit integer. The solution is simple: look at that number, and see if it is in the range 48-57, which is the range of SCII codes for the characters '0' - '9'.

Starting on line 1315 of the `scanf()` [source code](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/vfscanf.c;h=7356eeb3626665a0524bbf1be37398ea22e05d7e;hb=HEAD) we can see this in action. `scanf()` is actually more complicated, though - it also looks at multi-byte characters to determine the numeric value. Line 1740 is where the magic happens and that character is actually converted into a number. Finally, and possibly this is the most useful, the [`strtol()`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/strtol.c;h=1c63afb6fe5112b3c96d9e75677c8328db3de128;hb=f0bf9cb92c28c9ec0ac3376d87055e9d14610082) function does the looping to perform that conversion.

Answer (score 3):

The input is always a string.  If `scanf` is expecting an integer (because you passed it `"%d"`), it attempts to convert the string to an integer for you.

Comment: But whatever we input it would be a sequence of ascii values that are all numbers. Isn't it?

Comment: ASCII values that represent numbers, you mean.  scanf takes the character '9', decides it represents a number, and converts it to an integer 9.

Comment: Yes that's what it should do. The keyboard will send ascii characters only.

Comment: Detail: As C defines a _string_, input is rarely ever a string as it lacks a null character.  Input is a sequence of characters.

Answer (score 2):

In scanf statement you are mentioning %d which is holding integer only so by default it understood that the variable as integer

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the `scanf` function matches regular expressions based on the conversion specifier you pass.  If you specify `%d`, that tells `scanf` to match input against a regular expression that's one or more characters between `'0'` and `'9'` (optionally with a leading `+` or `-` character).  It then converts that sequence of characters to the equivalent integer value.

A *very* simplistic version might look something like this:

```
while (isdigit(c = fgetc(stream))
  val = val * 10 + valueOf(c); 
ungetc(c, stream);
```

where `isdigit` is a standard library function that returns true (non-zero) if the character value represents a decimal digit, and `valueOf` is a user-defined function that maps the character representing an integer (`'0'` - `'9'`) to the equivalent integer value (`0` - `9`) (I'm not aware of a standard library function that does that for individual character values).  Why not just subtract `'0'` from `c` to get the equivalent integer value?  Depending on the encoding, it's not guaranteed that all decimal integer characters will be laid out in order (All The World Is Not ASCII); best to delegate the actual conversion to a function that's aware of the current encoding.

Answer (score 0):

It tries to parse a valid decimal integer from the beginning of the stream, in practice optional + or - and then sequence of one or more digits.

Comment: Could you please explain how does it parse ? For eg. how will it differentiate between an A and the value 65 because A will be passed as 65 - its ascii value ?

Comment: Uh scant tries to read the ASCII representation of a decimal integer here. Letter A is not part of such.

Answer (score 0):

It basically uses a loop like:

```
while (isdigit((ch=getchar()))
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand the `%d` format specifier.  It does *not* return the ASCII value of the entered character (you can use `%c` for that); it returns the integer that the characters represent.  So, on an input character of `'9'`, `%d` returns the value 9 - not the ASCII value of `'9'`.

(Well, `%d` actually looks at a sequence of characters, so if the input is `'9'` followed by `'0'` followed by `' '`, it'll interpret that as 90).